# Applying a for loop to a conditional statement

Tags: python

Here is an example (code snippet from http://anh.cs.luc.edu/python/hands-on/3.1/handsonHtml/ifstatements.html):

```
if weight > 50:
    print("There is a $25 charge for luggage that heavy.")
print("Thank you for your business.")
```

I`d like to put the whole code in i.e. "for" loop. It would be super easy with a for(..){ *above code goes here* }. 
Still I cannot find a way to do it this way, I need to write the for loop and indent the whole block below. I think I am missing something here...

Comment: If you have a specific question, please post your code and ask it - otherwise, this reads like a rant.

Comment: Please, leave a reason for downvoting.

Comment: Because it's a troll question. 12" is perfectly big enough to run multiple windows, and even if for some completely unknown reason you are restricted to using nano in your terminal rather than a more capable editor like Vim, nano itself can easily indent multiple lines with a couple of keystrokes, as a simple Google search would reveal (for example https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/106251/how-to-indent-multiple-lines-in-nano).

Comment: And, of course, Python was initially released in 1991, well before "hipster offices" and "22 inch ultra hd screens".

Comment: it not a troll question, not by any mean. It may be a little bit rantish but that`s about it.

Comment: There's actually a flag for these types of questions: "primarily opinion based" so you're getting downvotes and your question will probably be closed... this is simply the wrong forum for that, that's it.

Comment: But I still don't understand your edit. Yes, you put the `for` before, then select the next three lines and indent them, usually with a single keystroke (eg tab). Why is that a problem?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because I laughed harder than I should have. Also, this is not a serious question.

Comment: Coldspeed - thankyou for the edit, it made the question clear and removed the rantish part. I am a noob in Py, so probably the answer is really easy. In such case I expect it soon :-)

Comment: @Caterpillaraoz: The really easy answer is: use an editor that lets you indent multiple selected lines simultaneously and know your shortcuts. Daniel Roseman already linked you the answer for nano.

Comment: Thankyou Shai for just providing the answer. And by the way, if I "just need to use and editor that..." I am basically using a tool to make up for the language`s shortcoming. I can edit my C files in nano in a second...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot escape python's indentation. What you can do is put your block of code in a function and the you only need to indent the single line with the function call.
Instead of

```
if condition:
   # code
   # code 
   # code...
```

Have a function

```
def my_code_block():
   if condition:
       # code
       # code 
       # code...
```

And then, in the caller function

```
for i in xrange(10):
    my_code_block( ... )
```

You only indent one line...

Comment: OK, this is the answer I was looking for. Thankyou! Still, as an opinion, GREAT language, let down by a nonsense choice.  Why not let programmers just  use the *&/@~ parentheys if they`d like. It would make quick experimentations on big codes way faster.

Comment: @Caterpillaraoz nothing is perfect ;)

Answer (score 5):

You can use as many parenthesis in Python as you want, especially for your `if` statement:

```
if(( (True) )
   and (1==1) ):
    print("It's really true")
```

Edit: The original question has been heavily modified, so this answer might no longer apply to the modified question.

Comment: Maybe my question is unclear: when working on a smaller screen it is impossible to have block defined by spaces. I need to be able to do if(true){a=d+f, c= 4+d} else {c=d}.